# cq5 - Using iparsys and overriding the parent content

Tags: aem

We are using an iparsys to display a text component at the parent level. The child pages inherit the content successfully. However at the child level we are not able to edit this or reorder it within the child level.

Basically we would like to 'override' the parent inherited content. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I feel this is the case for [MSM](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/multi_site_manager.html). Live copy allows you to use the inherited values but override it as you wish to.

Comment: Did you try disabling inheritance for that particular page alone ?

Comment: @rakhi4110 we still want inheritance to be enabled. However we want to be able to edit/override it from the child level though

Comment: I think you would need to stop the inheritance of this item and create a new one on the level you want to override it which will then be inherited down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot override the content of the `iparsys` in children pages. That is a limitation when use `iparsys`.
Instead, you can use `InheritanceValueMap` for inheritance and overriden.

ref:

1. [javadoc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/inherit/InheritanceValueMap.html)
2. [how to use](http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2012-07-23/good-know-inheritancevaluemap/)